# JavaScript function's memory size

Tags: javascript, function, memory

This seems rather obvious to me, but I just wanted to make sure. In terms of memory used when the `foo` function is stored, would it better to do this:

```
function foo(){
    var hey = {};
    hey.a = 1;
    hey.b = 1;
    alert('done');
}
```

or

```
function foo(){
    var hey = getHey();
    alert('done');
}
function getHey(){
    var hey = {};
    hey.a = 1;
    hey.b = 1;
    return hey;
}
```

Since `getHey()` is just going to be a reference to the actual function, I'm not sure whether it stores `foo` as is, or with an embedded `getHey`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logically the function will be stored in memory while the parent scope lives. and that reference does take a bit of memory but the real danger is usually the overhead when calling function in a loop, just having a single function call inside a large for-loop could add a lot of processing time.

Comment: So, if I stored a couple thousand instances of `foo` in a hash, the hash would take up the same amount of memory for both cases?

Comment: the program itself in memory would probably be slightly bigger but the variables declared should take the same. usually this is not an issue though as i described above, the time it takes to read that function (call overhead) will amount to huge perf. loss.

Answer (score 0):

They're separate functions. What'd probably save some space however is:

```
function foo() {
  var hey = { a: 1, b: 1 };
}
```